# SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am running vb.net scripts using asp.net version 4 under IIS on my local windows 7 machine. I can access and update data on my local sql server 2012 but when I try to use any stored proceedure in the same database I get the following error.

> SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure

I have run aspnet_regsql.exe against my local sql server and have sucessfully created a aspnetdb.
What do I need to do from here?

Comment: Does the account you are connecting with have access to those procedures?

Comment: What are the names (schema and name) of the stored procedures you are trying to access?

Comment: The account that I am connecting with certainly has access to the tables in the same database. Is there a better wat to check that it has access to the proceedures?

Comment: There names for example are dbo.createsession and the schema is dbo

Comment: Just to clarify, "I can access and update data on my local sql server 2012" means you can do it from within your ASP code?

Comment: the accesing to my local sql server is all via my asp code

Comment: Can you post 1) your connection string, 2) a sample call direct to the tables and 3) a sample call of a stored procedure?

Comment: I have found a way of fixing the problem.  I changed my web.cofig to ;-       <add name="Webapp" connectionString="Server=ssss; Database=dddd; User Id = uuuu; Password = xxx yyy zzz; Integrated Security=True; Integrated Security=SSPI" /> By adding Database=dddd;